# How can i Detect if the client change enable ad blocker again

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if use enable ad blocker on my website this my code but now I want to know if the user enable it again how can I check without loop , anyway to detect changes in extensions
or someone have another idea!, I see websites when change the enable or disable adblocker reload auto

```js
//Ad Blocker 
window.onload = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if ($('.body-ad').filter(':visible').length == 0) {
            document.querySelector('#DetectBlocker').style.display = "block"
            document.querySelector('body').style.position = "relative"
            document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = "hidden"
        }
    }, (1000 * 5))
}
```

also this code does not working on loop

Answer (score 0):

You can't check without loop. Even if you use event or something like that you are using listener that is kind of loop simulated.

Note that in this situation you can't use event because javascript events deal with `User Interaction`.

Also there is a Jquery [plugin](https://github.com/shaunbowe/jquery.visibilityChanged) that gives you an event `visibilityChanged` you can attach your element.

But I think a straightforward way is to use `setInterval` like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
                if ($('.body-ad').filter(':visible').length == 0) {
                    document.querySelector('#DetectBlocker').style.display = "block"
                    document.querySelector('body').style.position = "relative"
                    document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = "hidden"
                }
            }, (1000))
```